# XSL and XML - Set div ids to diferenciate them

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have the following:

```
<xsl:template match="MapSet">
    <div class="mapset" id="position()">
         <Content of div here>
    </div>  
</xsl:template>
```

I want to have different ids where position() is. I want to be able to keep only one div visible at a time. The ids would help me with that.

I would like to have an output like this:

```
    <div class="mapset" id="id1">
         <Content of div1 here>
    </div>  
    <div class="mapset" id="id2">
         <Content of div2 here>
    </div>  
    <div class="mapset" id="id3">
         <Content of div3 here>
    </div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your question? Your post lacks a problem, more XSLT code for context, the XML input you have and the output you expect.

Comment: @MathiasMüller , I have added the desired output.

Comment: It's quite redundant to have an ID attribute that contains "id". Is a number not sufficient as the value of @id? If you  want good answers add your XML input, too, along with more XSLT code - as I've said already.

Comment: @MathiasMüller , I have solved the problem. The id in the name doesnt matter, what I needed was to differentiate the mapsets.

Comment: @MathiasMüller it depends on your version of HTML.  Per spec HTML 4 and XHTML "id" attributes must be strings that would be valid as element names - they can't start with a digit.  HTML 5 relaxes this to allow IDs that are entirely numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the following code to solve the issue:

```
 <div class="mapset">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">mapset<xsl:number/></xsl:attribute>
 </div>
```

It now outputs:

```
<div class="mapset" id="mapset1">
     <Content of div1 here>
</div>  
<div class="mapset" id="mapset2">
     <Content of div2 here>
</div>  
<div class="mapset" id="mapset3">
     <Content of div3 here>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've answered your question successfully, which is good! But did you know about [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates), which provide an alternate approach to this.

Try this, for example

```
<div class="mapset" id="mapset{position()}">
     <Content of div here>
</div>
```

The Attribute Value Templates are denoted by the curly-braces. They indicate an expression to be evaluated, rather to be output literally. This should also give you the output you need.

Attribute Value Templates are often preferred because they are less verbose than writing **xsl:attribute** and the syntax is very closer to what is eventually output.